# static_pointer_cast for array specialization of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Acording to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast a `static_pointer_cast` is only valid if `static_cast<T*>((U*)0)` is well formed. Neither GCC, Clang, nor MSVC accept tjhe following static cast for pointers but do so for `shared_ptr` (https://godbolt.org/z/xs1b6jjEG):

```
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int[]> p1;
    auto p2 = std::static_pointer_cast<int>(p1); // OK

    using UnboundedArray = int[];
    auto p3 = static_cast<int*>((UnboundedArray*)0); // Not OK
}
```

As mentioned above the standard says that `static_pointer_cast` is only valid if the same cast of the pointers is valid. So, is the `static_pointer_cast` valid or not?

**Update**:

After some iterations, it seems like the `static_cast` above changed between C++17 and C++20.

C++17: https://godbolt.org/z/ns7oMdbd7
C++20: https://godbolt.org/z/Wjreo4oKq

**Update**:

I Have reformulated the question to cover the conversion between `shared_ptr<int[]>` and `shared_ptr<int>`.

Comment: [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) doesn't have an array specialization. Only [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) have.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Looking at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared it seems like array specialization of shared_ptr was not introduced before C++20.

Comment: I stand corrected. At least the index operator was introduced with C++17: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_at

Comment: "*MSVC complains.*" I can't reproduce it, your code [compiles fine for 3 compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/1Yrn331YY).

Comment: @康桓瑋 You are correct. Latest version does compile it. I accidentally compiled with version 19.00.

Comment: @康桓瑋 But even the latest MSVC version does not allow the static cast for raw pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The conversion is to `int(*)[]`, which certainly does exist.

Comment: @Jonas Can't reproduce that either (https://godbolt.org/z/Gd8MsWdxP).

Comment: @user17732522 Interesting that the C++ version has an effect.

Comment: @Jonas Not all that surprising. Before C++20 conversion to arrays of unknown bounds was not permitted. https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0388r4.html was accepted for C++20.

Comment: Looks like cppreference is missing a `typename std::shared_ptr<T>::element_type` map for T and U on that line.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont The standard doesn't use the element_type either: https://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared.cast#1 But since C++20 it is a "Mandates" clause rather than a precondition. So cppreference is not up-to-date (and it seems that neither are the compilers).

Comment: @user17732522 That does seem like the answer to my question. So, would you care to briefly formulate your last comment as an answer? Thank you.

Comment: @user17732522 Ah, that looks like a bug in the standard; it should probably read `static_cast<T*>((typename std::shared_ptr<U>::element_type*)nullptr)` is well formed.  (Not on the `T`, as we don't want casting between `shared_ptr<base[]>` and `shared_ptr<derived[]>`).